# Solving multivariable modulo equations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fixed-point-theorems

I am being asked to find fixed points of further iterations of the Cat map, which is defined as:

$$C(x,y) = (2x+y , x+y) \pmod 1 $$ for $(x,y)$ an element of $[0,1)$

Hence the equation to solve the fixed points for the 2nd iteration of this cat map would look like this:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = 5x + 3y \pmod 1 \\
y = 3x + 2y \pmod 1
\end {cases}
$$

I have no idea how to solve these, short of having to solve ~ 7 x 4 simultaneous equations (as the domain limits mod(1) from $0 \to 7$). I've attempted solving the first few and all that happens is I end up throwing out most solutions as they don't provide an answer in the domain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok well I just manually solved that equation and found 4 sets of solutions:


(0.2 , 0.4) & (0.4 , 0.8) & (0.6 , 0.2) & (0.8 , 0.6)

But now I need to solve for C^3 which is about 850 solutions I need to check for whether they are in they domain of [0,1), so is there a better way of doing this?